# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list

Tags: python, recursion

I tries to write program that will be append to the list recursively

```
def string(times,char):
    list=[]
    list.append(char)
    if times==0:
        print(list)
    else:
        return [list] + string(times-1 ,char)
string(3,input('text'))
```

and when I start the code, I got error

> **TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list**

Comment: In all tail positions you need a `return`, but in the case when `times == 0` you  print someting to terminal, then you calculate `string(3,input('text'))`, but that value is **never** returned. At the end of every python function there is a `return None`. The error is trying to use that in the concatenation later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when `times` is `0` your function prints the list but returns `None`. That means `[list] + string(times-1 ,char)` tries to concatenate `None` to a list and that is not allowed.

Use `return` instead of `print` and this problem will be solved.